# Casting to a collection with a dynamic type

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I set generic type dynamically?

```
 public class A
    {
        public int X { get; set; }

        public A()
        {
            X = 9000;
        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {

        public void Test()
        {
            List<A> theList = new List<A>() {
                new A { X = 1 },
                new A { X = 2 }               
            };


            object testObj = theList;
            var argType = testObj.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];


            Foo(testObj as ICollection<argType>); // ?                                           

        }

        public void Foo<T>(ICollection<T> items) where T:new()
        {
            T newItem = new T();    
            items.Add(newItem);    

        }
```

Comment: That's not how generics work.

Comment: BoltClock, how should it be done?

Comment: I should note that reflection and generics aren't the best of friends... in many ways it is tempting to just use the non-generic `IList`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do in "regular" c# you would use reflection to obtain the MethodInfo, then use MakeGenericMethod() and Invoke(). However, this is easier:

```
Foo((dynamic)testObj);
```

The reflection approach here is:

```
var method = typeof(Class1).GetMethod("Foo").MakeGenericMethod(argType);
method.Invoke(this, new object[] { testObj });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, because in the Foo function you are supposed to do something with the collection, and there's no guarantee that the type will be safe.

The only way is using an "object" then casting to the proper type within the Fooo function.

Comment: Marc's given two ways it can be done - one with reflection directly and one with dynamic typing. If you reckon it can't be done, it would be worth saying why you think his answer wouldn't work.

Comment: That's right. I posted my comment before the Marc's one. However, I didn't know the reflection way. I try to avoid whenever possible, and I also agree with Marc that generic and reflection are hard to coexists. I remind an old article of Bea Costa where she had to invent an awful trick to make the WPF working decently with an IEnumerable<T> interface. She wasn't Bea, but the hardness of the expression of reflection vs generics.